# How to align text vertically in div tag, which is inside th tag?

Tags: jquery, html, css, button

I've tried everything, I want the red button in the center next to the heading and the text"df" inside the button. Please suggest

HTML code:

```
<th style="width:11.5%;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;" valign="middle">
Table heading1 
<div id="myButton1" class='myButtons' style=" text-align: left;" >df</div>
</th>
```

CSS:

```
$(".myButtons").button().css({ 'width': '15%','height' : '10px','line-height': '10px',
                               'padding-top': '0px',
                               'padding-bottom': '0px',
                               'font-size': '11px',
                               'background':'#ff0000',
                               'font-family': 'Century Gothic, sans-serif', 
                               'text-align':'left',
                               'border-color':'#ff0000',
                               'border-radius':'2px',
                              });
```

[Output right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdCvI.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting your button `display` property to `inline-block` and adding `vertical-align: middle` to it as well, like this:

```js
$(".myButtons").css({
  'width': '15%',
  'height': '10px',
  'line-height': '10px',
  'display': 'inline-block',
  'padding-top': '0px',
  'padding-bottom': '0px',
  'font-size': '11px',
  'background': '#ff0000',
  'font-family': 'Century Gothic, sans-serif',
  'text-align': 'left',
  'border-color': '#ff0000',
  'border-radius': '2px',
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th style="width:11.5%;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;" valign="middle">
      Table heading1
      <div id="myButton1" class='myButtons' style=" text-align: left;">df</div>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Somehow i'm still getting the same output, i have just increased the height to make the text look as if it is inside the <div>.

Comment: Can you post a snippet so I can see what's happening live?